# Using MQ from Weblogic JMS

Tags: jms, weblogic, ibm-mq

I am using Weblogic JMS to connect MQ using bindings file. I had existing MQ connection. In a recent change one more MQ queue was added and binding file was updated accordingly adding new queue details. I put the new binding file in separate location and referring that in JMS for new queue. After that can see FFDC logs being generated saying more active connections.

At present I have two binding file on my server on separate locations. One has original details and the second one has original plus new details. Will this cause any issues and creating more connections?

Comment: You didn't provide any specific errors or details on your bindings file.   Why not replace the existing file with the new file that had the added queue?

Comment: Please can you show us a few details from the header in the FFDC logs so we can more fully understand the problem you are describing